# UTF-8 Character Encoding in SQL

Tags: ms-access, utf-8, special-characters

I am trying out [Bullzip's Access to mySQL app](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) on an Access DB full of special chars like é and ä.  The app allows you to specify UTF-8 encoding but in the resulting SQL file I get "Vieux CarrÃ©" instead of "Vieux Carré".

I tried opening the SQL file in [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) and doing a UTF-8 conversion but it does not resolve this issue as I guess it is converting "Ã©" and never sees the "é"?

What is a Good™ solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the UTF-8 to Unicode conversion into or out of Access. Access, like SQL Server, can only natively store data in ASCII format or Unicode (UTF-16) (With Unicode compression off). In order to ensure a given value was stored properly, you would need to convert it to Unicode on storage and convert it back to UTF-8 on retrieval. You may be able to use the `StrConv` function for such a purpose.

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware of that limitation.  That is very enlightening!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh If you use the `ADODB.Command` and pass the values as `adVarWChar` ADO should handle the conversion to unicode for you, rather than having to manually convert.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Bullzip convertor now, so it could still help someone.

It doesn´t show the special characters right if I have my pc language set to english. I have to switch it back to czech (language of the special characters) and it works now and SQL looks correct.